# How to check if a property value exists in an array and update another property

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a struct Ride with a few properties

```
struct Ride {

var date:String?
var dateAsDate:Date?
var description:String?
var destination:String?
var distance:Double?
var societe:String?
var tarif:Double?
var car:String?
var docId:String?
```

}

I have my main [Ride], with all Rides from the database, that I managed to display in a tableview.

Now I want to create a view to display stats related to those Rides in a tableview.

For example, a section "By destination" in the tableview that display a row by destination with the count of rides to that destination.

I think I have to :

- create a struct "Destination" with name and count properties
- Create an array of Destinations
- loop through my main array of Rides
- for each ride destination
- check if it already exists in my [Destination]
- if it does add 1 to the count property
- else create a Destination
- append the [Destination] with it

Is this the right logic? and how can I implement it in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using `reduce` to create a dictionary with the destination as key and the count as values

```
let destinations = array.reduce(into: [:]) {
    $0[$1.destination, default: 0] += 1
}
```

If you want to filter out nil values you can also use `compactMap`

```
let destinations2 = array.compactMap {$0.destination}.reduce(into: [:]) {
    $0[$1, default: 0] += 1
}
```

and a last alternative that includes nil values in another way than the first alternative

```
let destinations = array.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) {
    let destination = $1.destination ?? "None"
    $0[destination, default: 0] += 1
}
```